# Como hacer una comparación entre la distancia de puntos faciales?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api

**Buenas,** tengo el inconveniente en el cual requiero hacer una **comparación facial** entre rostros y por mi investigación determine que se realiza por los puntos de referencia faciales que se encuentra en un rostro. Por ahora puedo obtener y procesar esta información usando la [API de Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/face-detection-concepts) con su sencilla forma de obtener **rostros y puntos de referencias faciales** de los mismos. Por ahora voy bien **pero mi inconveniente** se presenta al tratar de obtener la distancia entre puntos faciales ya que estos de acuerdo a la proximidad de la cámara varia su tamaño y no me sirve para poder comparar. En si en conclusión lo que busco es la manera de poder comparar la distancia entre puntos referenciales sin importar la distancia solo la calidad de imagen, tengo entendido que **en teoría** es la mejor forma para comparar un rostro.

El codigo que uso para obtener los [Puntos De Referencia Facial:](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial)

```
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
    Face face = faces.valueAt(i);
    for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
        //aqui obtengo los tamaños pero estos varían

        float x = landmark.getPosition().x;
        float y = landmark.getPosition().y;


    }
}
```

Esta pequeña fracción de código me permite poder obtener los **Landmarks** o **Puntos De Referencia Facial**. Esta forma obtengo las distancia entre cada punto pero esta varia de acuerdo a la proximidad de la cámara.

**Muchas gracias** y espero su apoyo.

Comment: Creo que vi con open vc lo hicieron pero necesita dato de una imagen con distancia conocida, aunque puedes hacerlo sacando una foto tuya y calcular los datos de distancia conocida, asi calculas la escala con eso calculas la distancia en cualquier foto.

Comment: Puede armar una respuesta ? Aunque de todas formas voy a investigar lo que me comentó gracias

Comment: Hola @Abraham.P lo que deseas es la distancia entre por ejemplo ojos nariz y boca en centimetros por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde la prudencia ya que no he trabajado nunca con reconocimiento facial, creo que sabiendo los puntos de referencia de la imagen origen se calculan las distancias (d1, d2, d3, d4, ...). Ahora en la imagen que vas a comparar se cogen los puntos de referencia y se calculan las mismas distancias igualmente (D1, D2, D3, D4, ...).

d1/D1 = a

d2/D2 = b

d3/D3 = c

d4/D4 = d

Si **a**, **b**, **c**, y **d** son iguales, entonces ambas imágenes comparadas son iguales. Si además dicho valor es 1 entonces hablamos que están en la misma escala.
Si los valores **a**, **b**, **c**, y **d** no concuerdan (son diferentes) entonces la comparación es negativa.

Espero que se me haya entendido.

Saludos.

Comment: amigo lo que pasa es que las distancias varian por eso hay que hacer un proceso de probabilidades demas de un 70% de exactitud

Comment: Correcto. En el caso expuesto a, b, c y d nos arrojan valores de proporcionalidad entre las distancias. Tanto más parecidos sean todos los valores más exacta es determinar la concordancia de una imagen con otra. Aquí ya interviene el margen de error con que se quiera dar por buena la coincidencia. Usando la desviación estándar podemos calcular cómo de alejados están los datos de la media. Mientras más baja sea la desviación estándar, más cerca están los valores de la media y por tanto más iguales son los datos y por ende mayor coincidencia.

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi ignorancia en reconocimiento facial y por atrevimiento yo trataría de hacer esto:

Calcularía el punto central

```
(max(x)-min(x))/2 (max(y)-min(y))/2
```

Calcularía las distancias al punto central de cada landmark.

```
 sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2).
```

y las normalizaría

```
z=(x-Media)/Desviación Estándar.
```

Comment: Amigo su idea es interesante muy interesante, pero en teoria el punto central que puedo tomar es la nariz como punto base, pero en el resto me perdi puede explicar mas claro el proceso ?